# How to set an UIActivityIndicatorView when loading a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I have two `UITableViewController`s, A and B. When I tap one cell in table A, I will use `UINavigationController` to push table view controller B. But the data of B is downloaded from Internet, which takes several seconds. So I want to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` when loading B. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 53):

You can add *UIActivityIndicatorView* as cell's **`accessoryView`**.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryView = spinner;
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [spinner release];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work at all... Can you give me a sample project?

Comment: The question is about displaying a large spinner in the center of the screen, not within every cell.

Comment: Try adding [spinner startAnimating] to the above sample: It should allow you to put a spinner in the accessory view of table A until table B is ready to load, if that is what you want.

Comment: OMG! I've really forgot to add it. Thanks Tim Dean.

Comment: @Wu Linson, Sorry I have forgot to add am important line. You should add [spinner startAnimating]; See my updated answer.

Comment: That really works! to put the spinner in the middle of a cell i changed the `spinner.frame` to `spinner.frame =CGRectMake (cell.center.y, cell.center.x, cell.frame.size.width,     cell.frame.size.height);`

Answer (score 30):

In viewDidLoad of tableview B class, add an activity indicator.

```
// Create the Activity Indicator.
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    // Position it at the center of the ViewController.
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)])
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Now call your method that downloads data from the network.

```
myDownloadMethod()
```

Do it in a different thread if you don't want the UI to be non responsive during the process.

read this thread for that.
[Can I use a background thread to parse data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965265/can-i-use-a-background-thread-to-parse-data/6965350#6965350)

When you are notified that the contents are downloaded, stop the indicator.

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

Now you can call `tableview.reloadData()` for reloading the table to display the new contents.

Comment: can you give me more details?

Answer (score 8):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView * activityindicator1 = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 200, 30, 30)];
[activityindicator1 setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityindicator1 setColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview:activityindicator1];
[activityindicator1 startAnimating];

[self performSelector:@selector(callfunction) withObject:activityindicator1 afterDelay:1.0];

-(void)callfunction
{
// Here your stuf
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's work well for me, you can try it:

Call `[activityIndicator startAnimating]` when **`didHighlightRowAtIndexPath`**, 
and call `[activityIndicator stopAnimating]` when **`didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath`** useful than `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)runIndicatorAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath display:(BOOL)playing{ 
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryView = activityIndicator;
    playing == YES ?[activityIndicator startAnimating]:[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self runIndicatorAtIndexPath:indexPath display:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self runIndicatorAtIndexPath:indexPath display:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code below will display a spinner at the footer of the table view if more data is available on the server. You can change it according to your logic of fetching data from server.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     /* set cell attributes here */
     NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
     NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
     if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex)) {
         if(isMoreDataAvailableOnserver)
         {
             [self showSpinnerAtFooter];
             [self getMoreDataFromServer];
         }
         else {
             [self hideSpinnerAtFooter];
         }
     }
     return cell;
}

- (void)hideSpinnerAtFooter {
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
}

- (void)showSpinnerAtFooter {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = spinner;
}
```