# CHCSVParser with NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsurl

I am trying to use CHCSVParser to parse a csv file. I have looked at [Dave DeLongs answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961367/basics-introduction-to-using-chcsvparser), but do not seem to get it working. It seems that some things have changed since then and I am asked to use NSURL instead of NSString. So I tried a few things, and now I have the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"csv"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfDelimitedURL:url delimiter:','];
```

But get the following error:

> 2016-01-20 03:32:31.300 CSVParserNoTwo[61288:14031346] *** Assertion
>   failure in +[NSArray
>   arrayWithContentsOfDelimitedURL:options:delimiter:error:],
>   /Users/dominik/Coding/Objective-C/CSVParseNo1/CSVParserNoTwo/CSVParserNoTwo/CHCSVParser.m:822
>   2016-01-20 03:32:31.301 CSVParserNoTwo[61288:14031346] Invalid
>   parameter not satisfying: fileURL

It might also be that the original answer by Dave is not superseded yet and I just don't know better, since I am a complete beginner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Change `URLWithString:` to `fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: thank you, it builds, but it gives me: [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter

Comment: Then you must be passing in a `nil` path. Use the debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: found it! thanks a lot!!